# How to get actual data from one closure into another?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a block moment. In `getDataByDate` in `case .success` I get some data. It's array. After that I need to push that array into `callAnother` and work with elements of array in loop. Every element I push into `myAnotherMethod` and in `completion` block I'd like to create `arrayForDataSourceSave` and sent it into `self?.dataSource.save(data: data, add: arrayForDataSourceSave`

Everytime my `add` is empty. How to fix this?

```
private func callAnother(data: [AnyModel], completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    var arrayForDataSourceSave: []()
    for element in data {
        guard let id = element.id else { return }
        APIService.myAnotherMethod(id: id, completion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let well):
                arrayForDataSourceSave.append(well)
                print(well)
            case .error(let error):
                print("request error: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
    completion()
}

func refresh(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    APIService.getDataByDate(date: date, completion: { [weak self] (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            self?.callAnother(data: data, completion: {
                self?.dataSource.save(data: data, add: arrayForDataSourceSave)
            })
        case .error(let error):
            print("request error: \(error)")
        }
        completion()
    })
}
```

Comment: are you trying to pass arrayForDataSourceSave to refresh function ? I guess you can pass array back in completion block -: "private func callAnother(data: [AnyModel], completion: @escaping (result:[YourArray])->()) ". Call completion in success.

Comment: Are you sure the code is passing compilation?
`var arrayForDataSourceSave: []()` invalid syntax you are calling the constructor in the wrong place, it should be `var arrayForDataSourceSave: [Any] = []` or `var arrayForDataSourceSave = [Any]()`
And how are you accessing `arrayForDataSourceSave` from the `refresh(completion:)` function if it is a `callAnother(data:completion:)` function's local variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the decision for that task with `DispatchGroup` and my code works good:

```
private func callAnother(data: [AnyModel]) {

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var arrayForDataSourceSave = [AnyModel]()

    for element in data {
        guard let id = element.id else { return }
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        APIService.myAnotherMethod(id: id, completion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let well):
                arrayForDataSourceSave.append(well)
                print(well)
            case .error(let error):
                print("request error: \(error)")
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        self?.dataSource.save(data: data, add: arrayForDataSourceSave)
    }
}

func refresh(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    APIService.getDataByDate(date: date, completion: { [weak self] (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            self?.callAnother(data: data)
        case .error(let error):
            print("request error: \(error)")
        }
        completion()
    })
}
```